# Custom aggregation for tf.GradientTape().gradient? (TF2.0)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

As far as I know, the tf.gradients function provides option to choose the aggregation method for summarizing the gradients from multiple sources.
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/gradients

However according to the Tensorflow API documentation, the tf.GradientTape().gradient method has no such option.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape

So my questions are as follows:

1. Is there any way to change the aggregation method in tf.GradientTape().gradient?
2. If not, is there any way to obtain the gradient with a custom aggregation method which is compatible with eager execution?